# Jquery/Javascript - store last 4 letters of string (cross browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, substr

I've written a quick image swap class that switches images on hover by placing adding '_grey' to the image src.  The code works great throughout the site in all browsers apart from ie6. The substr doesnt seem to work properly here - any advice please!?

Code as follows -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var initImg;    
    $('img.swapGrey').hover(function() {


        initImg = $(this).attr("src");  
        var imgType = (initImg).substr(-4);
        alert(initImg);
        var greyImg = initImg.slice(0, -4) + "_grey" + imgType;
        alert(greyImg);

        $(this).attr("src",greyImg);

            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src",initImg);

    });


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `slice` rather than `substr`. `substr` is non-standard, while `slice` is specified (including negative positions) in the ECMAScript 3 spec, and is supported in all the major browsers, including IE 6.

Answer (score 1):

just use a positive starting position in IE.

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support negative values for the argument of `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in `load` event rather than `ready`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code...
});
```

The reason for using `load` event is that by the time images have completely loaded into the page unlike `ready` event.

Comment: should not matter to the mouseover event unless you are quite fast (visually), even then...not the issue as the DOM will have the attr src set.

Answer (score 0):

More verbose than needs to be (to show the effect of the functions), but basically changes test.jpg to test_grey.jpg if test.jpg is the src of the img element.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var initImg;
        $('img.swapGrey').hover(function() {


            initImg = $(this).attr("src");
            var len = initImg.length - 4;
            var imgType = initImg.slice(len);
            alert(":"+imgType+":");
            alert(initImg + " is " + len +":"+ imgType);
            var greyImg = initImg.slice(0, -4) + "_grey" + imgType;
            alert(greyImg);

            $(this).attr("src", greyImg);

        }, function() {
            $(this).attr("src", initImg);
      });
 });
```